# Add LongPressGesture to many textfields

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit

I have many textfields to enter values for calculation.
For each textfield I also added a LongPressGestureRecognizer so that I can update my calculations with interim results that I store in the placeholders.

```
@IBAction func lTap1(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .began && lTap1.placeholder!.isNumeric
            {
            lTap1.text = lTap1.placeholder
            Calculation()
            }
    }
```

Is there a more convenient way with less code to add the long tap function to each text field instead of repeating the @IBAction function for lTap2, lTap3, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

First assign **tag** to all Textfields
then declare the array of TextFields there are two ways to declare

```
@IBOutlet var textFields: [UITextField]!
```

and

```
let textFields = [lTap1, lTap2, lTap3,...]
```

then

```
@objc func textFeildLongPressed(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let tag = sender.view?.tag else { return }
    guard let textField = textFields[tag] else {
        return
    }
    if sender.state == .began && textField.placeholder!.isNumeric {
        textField.text = textField.placeholder
        Calculation()
    }
}
```

Now assign gesture to all textFields in **viewDidLoad** function

```
textFields.forEach {
        let tap = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(textFeildLongPressed(_:)))
        tap.view?.tag = $0.tag
        $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        $0.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
```

Thanks.